# ejabbered xmpp server chat integration with django api

Tags: python, django, api, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to integrate ejabbered with django api. I am unable to understand which package to use. Can any one tell me the steps to integrate jabbered with django user table. I also want to know its flow to establish chat in app end.
I am unable to figure out the package to use in django for xmpp.

Any help will be appreciated. I know that i have to include the ejabbered password and username in user table.

Answer (score 1):

ejabberd allows to do handle authentication by an external script ([extauth](https://www.ejabberd.im/extauth)). There's a third-party Django app ([django-ejabberd-bridge](https://github.com/ffalcinelli/django-ejabberd-bridge)) which uses that mechanism to be able to use Django's user database for ejabberd authentication. That's what you're looking for. To quote from its README:

> It's a django app to integrate ejabberd XMPP server with Django
>
> Right now it just allows the ejabberd service to perform authentication against Django's authentication middleware.

The README also contains detailed steps how to set it up.

Comment: django-ejabberd-bridge will just install ejabberd application. I need to connect it with my django api and then create a new ejabberd user in signup api then register this user in ejabberd , to setup chat. Django ejabbered bridge is not telling anything about how to register a new user in ejabbered. I also need to get its jabbered id

Comment: Please read what django-ejabberd-bridge does. You don't need to somehow create the users in ejabberd as ejabberd will use Djangos database to get the user information from.